# Why model file load first than config file in laravel module

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, config

I have a problem with model and config file, I was trying to call the config in the model.

the code was like this in the model file

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    
    if (config('some-config.CONFIG_KEY') == 'ACTIVE')
        static::addGlobalScope(new SomeScope);
    
}
```

The `some-config.CONFIG_KEY` has 'ACTIVE' as a value but unexpectedly the system read it as `null`, so the condition doesn't match.

Did anyone encounter the same problem and what way to fix it?

I was trying to find the cause, the cause was the config file load later than the model file, so the config was return NULL

I hope the config file return the actual value

Answer (score 0):

Would you try `booted()` instead..

```php
protected static function booted()
{
    if (config('some-config.CONFIG_KEY') == 'ACTIVE'){
       static::addGlobalScope(new SomeScope);
    }
}
```